# HeidiSQL - How to Select Individual Columns Explicitly into Query Window?

Tags: heidisql

Apologies if title is unclear, couldn't think of a concise way to express this.

I'm wondering if HeidiSQL has some simple functionality to quickly create a new select query which explicitly lists every column contained in that table. In MS SQL Management Studio (And I believe also in MYSQL Workbench) this can be done just by right clicking the table and clicking 'New Select Query' or something along those lines.

This can be very useful for creating queries off tables containing many columns, where most but not all columns are desired, or where a handful of transformations are required. The alternative involves typing out every single column name individually. Creating a 'Create Table' query comes close to what I want, but includes all the column type descriptor information which needs to be manually deleted.

So for example what I want is, instead of:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
```

I need:

```
SELECT ID,
   Name,
   Location,
   Date,
   Value1,
   Value2
FROM MyTable
```

Is there any quick and easy way to use the UI to generate this in HeidiSQL?

Answer (score 5):

1. Click the relevant table in the database tree
2. Click on the `Query` tab
3. Expand the `Columns in <yourtable>` node in the right helpers box
4. Select wanted columns
5. Right click, and click `Generate SELECT...`

Like in the following figure:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ...

Solved by installing an older version of HeidiSQL.

For older versions, show the complete "selects columns" in the log field.

---

**Update 2015-03-18:**

I get the full SELECT doing a simple update on any table field.

Image: http://pt-br.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2nqtemr&s=8

*Sorry for the my English, I don't speak English very nice, I'm from Brazil = /.*

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending your answer little more to explain how it solves the problem.